# How can I add the countries' names upon the geochoropleth map ?

Tags: dictionary, names, dc.js

I'm working with dc.js and I'm about to create a world map.
How can I add the countries' names upon the geochoropleth map ?

Answer (score 2):

I create a crude example of this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/9VJHe/

1) First I attained the json file containing the centroids of all of the states: https://bitbucket.org/john2x/d3test/src/2ce4dd511244/d3/examples/data/us-state-centroids.json.  For the purposes of this example, I copied the json to the jsfiddle.

```
   var labels = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
                    {"type":"Feature","id":"01","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-86.766233,33.001471]},"properties":{"name":"Alabama","population":4447100}},
                    {"type":"Feature","id":"02","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-148.716968,61.288254]},"properties":{"name":"Alaska","population":626932}},
```

2) Then I added a svg element to the chart that would contain all of the labels:

```
      var labelG = d3.select("svg")
            .append("svg:g") 
            .attr("id", "labelG") 
            .attr("class", "Title");
```

3) Next I added a svg text element for every state in the labels json:

```
    labelG.selectAll("text") 
       .data(labels.features) 
       .enter().append("svg:text")
```

4) Then I positioned the text elements using the coordinates of the centroid.  To accomplish this you should use the projection from the chart to translate the coordinates to relative x and y values.

```
         .attr("x", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[0];}) 
         .attr("y", function(d){return project(d.geometry.coordinates)[1];}) 
         .attr("dx", "-1em");
```

Here is the final result:
[image]

You'll notice two problems:

- There isn't enough room to display all of the names in the northeast states
- The labels aren't centered very well

Both of these problems could be resolved by changing the labels json by manually moving the coordinates.

Note, I used this question as a basis for my answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/uAWkwnuNQ3Q

Comment: This new example at https://gist.github.com/proclamo/0fc304040b7036eb7785 uses the centroid of the state/country to place the label:  https://gist.github.com/proclamo/0fc304040b7036eb7785.  Looks promising.